# perl6/raku: how to I restrict the values allowed in a variable?

Tags: raku

Perl6/Raku

I would like to create a sub were only certain values are allowed to be passed to it.  And not passing the allowed value will create a checker error (perl6 -c).

How do I do this?

Many thanks,
-T

Hi Raiph,

In my WinPopUps module, I used the "where" method because it tells the user at a glance what the allowed values are.  I love it!   It is all about maintainability!  (By the way, the following is the monster your created!)

```
sub WinPopUp( Str $TitleStr, 
              Str $MessageStr,
              Str $Icons where   * ~~ "Exclamation"             |
                                      "Warning"                 |
                                      "Information"             |
                                      "Asterisk"                |
                                      "Question"                |
                                      "Stop"                    |
                                      "Error"                   |
                                      "Hand",
              Str $Buttons where * ~~ "AbortRetryIgnore"        | 
                                      "CancelTryAgainContinue"  |
                                      "Help"                    |
                                      "Ok"                      |
                                      "OkCancel"                |
                                      "RetryCancel"             |
                                      "YesNo"                   |
                                      "YesNoCancel" ) 
              is export( :WinPopUp ) {
```

Thank you for the help!
-T

Let me know if you want the whole module and where to post it

Comment: You can also store the values in an array constant and then reference them as `sub WinPopUp( … Str $Icons where * eq @icons.any, Str $Buttons where * eq @buttons…)`.  You might also consider using `Str()` instead of `Str` so that non-strings that can be stringified can be passed as well.

Comment: It is a module.  The main program can only see things that are inside the called sub

Comment: FWIW, I have collected a few Windows API related functions and constants along with NativeCall definitions. I can share. Stuff  from user32 and kernel32

Comment: Wold love to see them!  Native call is such an enigma to me.

Comment: Todd: the main program only needs to see the sub.  But any variables declared in the module, even if they aren't available to programs that import the module, are still available within the module.  So you can just immediately above the sub declaration, put my @icons = <foo bar>;

Comment: Copying from my comment on the accepted answer... `perl6 -c` only does compile-time checks. That doesn't include `where` clauses. They're only checked at run-time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply add a `where` condition on the values

```
sub foo( Int $binary where * ~~ 0|1 ) { ... }
```

The `where` condition can be an arbitrary code block ( or even a sub I believe ).

If you need the condition multiple times you can create a `subset`.

```
subset BinaryInt of Int where * ~~ 0|1;
```

and subsequently use that in the signature

```
sub foo( BinaryInt $binary ) { ... }
```

Note, this isn't just limited to subroutine signatures. The constraints/conditions are enforced everywhere

```
my BinaryInt $i = 0; 
$i++; 
$i++;
# -> Type check failed in assignment to $i; expected BinaryInt but got Int (2)
```

You can also have subsets of subsets:

```
subset FalseBinaryInt of BinaryInt where not *;
my FalseBinaryInt $i = 0; 
$i++; 
# -> Type check failed in assignment to $i; expected FalseBinaryInt but got Int (1)
```

Edit: JJ down there is right. In this case an enumeration is useful. This

```
sub WinPopUp( Str $TitleStr, 
              Str $MessageStr,
              MessageBoxIcons $Icons where   * ~~ Exclamation |
                                                  Information |
              ...
```

Paired with an enumeration like

```
enum MessageBoxIcons is export {
    Exclamation => 0x00000030,
    Information => 0x00000040,
    ...
}
```

protects you from random typos, as enum members are symbols, and if you mispell one, the compiler will catch it. Also you don't have to look up the values to feed into `MessageBoxW` (which is what you are doing I assume).

Speaking of `MessageBoxW`, I would call your sub `message-box` (in Raku we tend to use CamelCase only for Classes and Types and stuff) just to stay consistent with `MessageBoxW`

Comment: It *is* cool stuff. And @Todd has accepted your excellent answer. (And got my upvote and many others.) But FTR `perl6 -c` only does *compile-time* checks. That doesn't include `where` clauses. They're only checked at *run-time*.

Comment: Hi JJ, I use CamelCase all the time because I can type and it make no difference to me.  And CamelCase tells me what is my doing and what is Raku's doing. Make it very easy to tell apart.  For me, it makes it much more maintainable.  And for that to work, Raku needs to stay all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it would be probably the best to use [`enum`s](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-Enumeration-_Enums-_enum):

```
enum Icons <Exclamation Warning Information>;
sub pop-up( Icons $icon ) { $icon}; 
say pop-up( Information ); # OUTPUT: «Information␤»
```

However, you're using [Str](https://docs.raku.org/type/Str) already for some reason, so it might be better to use [subsets](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-subset-subset):

```
subset Icons of Str where * eq any <Exclamation Warning Information>;
sub pop-up( Icons $icon ) { $icon};
say pop-up( "Information" );
```

These have already been mentioned in [Holli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59222545/891440), although only "if you are going to use them several times". I would define a subset even if you're using it only one. It's safer, and also clearer, as well as testable.

Comment: Hi JJ, This is a module.  It is my understanding that the main program can only see what is inside the called module.  It is also my experience, although I have not tested it in several years.  I chose "where" because I could write the sub header in such a way that it was intuitive to the reader what values were accepted into the sub.  So, for maintainability.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hi Holli, I am not sure where your edit is.    Stack Exchange is not real friendly with the flow of information as they want you to edit your original stuff and the comment section doesn't allow for enough room to respond properly at times.  What were you referring to? Also, I do not know if a calling program can see anything in a module other than what is inside the sub that it calls. It is my experience that it can't, but that may have changed.  Subsets sound interesting.  I have no programs calling this module yet, so it would be pretty each to modify

Comment: HI JJ,I am not seeing "subset Icons of Str where * eq any <Exclamation Warning Information>;
sub pop-up( Icons $icon ) { $icon};
say pop-up( "Information" ); 
" bding caught by "perl6 -c xxx.pm6", so ???

Comment: @Todd bding? What do you mean?

Comment: Hi JJ, if I put "where   * ~~" on the sub declaration or if I do a subset, an incorrect entry called to the sub is not caught by the checker (-c) and both wait to be caught at run time.  And since I will be only using that set of commands once and placing it in the sub line makes it easier for someone (me at the moment) to find the parameters rather than digging around looking for the subset, I did not see the utility of using a subset.  (I can see a lot of utility when things are repeated though.)